# Determine root directory of application

Tags: php, apache

I am having a bit of trouble with relative path in php.  Within one of my classes I have the following code:

```
$iniPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/movies/config.ini";
$ini_array = parse_ini_file($iniPath, true);
```

This code works perfectly because it returns "/var/www/movies/config.ini".

But the problem is the code isn't transportable.  If its installed on another server they may not install it in /movies/.

tl;dr  How do I specify application directory as root directory in php?

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will give you the root directory. Do you mean the directory (relative to the root) in which the current script is running?

Comment: You should setup another variable for the folder/sub-folder that the potential user will use, and then replace `/movies/` with the variable's name. Maybe even add an `if` condition to boot. The variable could be something to the affect of `$folder="change_this";`

Comment: @BenM Yes, but where the application is running.  I have all my php classes in a folder called, classes.  So its relative to the application directory, not where that particular script is running

Comment: Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a safe method, it's just the rest that needs to be determined and re-thinked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is an infinite set of directories where one could decide to install the php app, I can't just use an if/else if/else to catch them all.

Comment: I did say "maybe" ;-)

Comment: @triunenature so your question is about "how to move the document_root and keep including file from the previous emplacmeent". If yes, maybe my answer can help you by defining constants and absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` to determine the current path relative to your application.

You can define a constant inside the first file called (or inside a config or bootstrap file) :

```
<?php
   define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__.'/');
   // and define some other base path 
   // you can also define everything in a separate file
   define('MOVIE_DIR', ROOT_DIR.'movies/');
   // and define absolute path
   define('CLASS_DIR', '/usr/local/share/something/that/will/never/change/');
   // then your code will looks like
   $iniPath = MOVIE_DIR . '/config.ini';
   $ini_array = parse_ini_file($iniPath, true);
```

**EDIT:** an other alternative (after reading your comments in your question) is to use [set_include_path](https://www.php.net/set_include_path) but, that's not often used.

Comment: I've never really used define, I just tried it.  In my index.php I did the define statement, then in my class document I did APP_ROOT . '/config.ini' and it said it couldn't find "APP_ROOT/config.ini".

How do I pass define from one php page to another?  Cookies?

Comment: no, you have to put all your define in one file (lets call it defines.php) . Then include that file in every file which have to use them. A basic pattern is to have index.php first line containing `require_once('config.php')` which contains define() and other initialization process that has to be done in all other .php files

Answer (score 0):

Try to checkout the PHP magic constants

```
__DIR__
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php